# How to setup read only access via mongolab api key

Tags: mongodb, mlab

I want to use mongolab from client js. I aware that reading data from db will be accessible for anyone who knows my API key. But I must to forbid modifying of database. I can't search for **actual information**. Only old posts, that could be already outdated (I hope guys from mongolab improving their product). I think that it may be possible because we have different API keys for each **account** user.

So, is it possible at current time to set read only access for **account** user?